# Display all posts that use a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, terms

I'm trying to display all the posts that use a custom taxonomy. I believe the issue is that it is my code is not generating an array of terms.

```
 $clients_terms = get_terms('clients');

    $clients_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'work',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'clients',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => array($clients_terms->slug)
        )
      )
    ) );
    if ( $clients_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul class="work_list">
      <?php while ( $clients_query->have_posts() ) : $clients_querys->the_post(); ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   </li>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
```

I'm able to generate posts for individual terms but not for all posts that use the taxonomy .

Comment: What is the output of `array($clients_terms->slug)`? That doesn't seem correct syntax to me. `get_terms()` returns an *array* of objects; *not* an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
'terms' => array($clients_terms->slug)
```

You define `$clients_terms` like so:

```
$clients_terms = get_terms('clients');
```

...which will return an *array of objects*. But you try to access it as an *object* in your query args. That should be producing some kind of PHP notice? (*Trying to get property of non-object*, or something?)

Try building the array, then passing it to `'terms'`:

```
// Get the array of objects
$clients_terms_objs = get_terms( 'clients' );

// Define terms array
$clients_terms = array();

// Step through array of objects,
// and populate terms array
foreach ( $clients_terms_objs as $clients_term_obj ) {
    $clients_terms[] = $clients_term_obj->slug;
}

// Construct query
$clients_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'work',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'tax_query' => array(
       array(
          'taxonomy' => 'clients',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $clients_terms
       )
    )
) );
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have resolved the issue but I wasn't getting any php notice? Thanks again

Comment: Do you have `WP_DEBUG` enabled?

Answer (score 1):

#### Here is an alternate solution using filters that doesn't require the get_terms() call.

```
/**
 * Extends WP_Query with a posts_join filter allowing you to query by taxonomy instead of tax_query using terms
 * Usage: <code> $query = new Query_By_Taxonomy( array( 'posts_per_page' => $foo, 'orderby' => $bar ) ); </code>
 *
 * @class Query_By_Taxonomy
 */
class Query_By_Taxonomy extends WP_Query {

    var $posts_by_taxonomy;
    var $taxonomy;

    function __construct( $args = array() ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_join', array( $this, 'posts_join' ), 10, 2 );
        $this->posts_by_taxonomy = true;
        $this->taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];

        unset( $args['taxonomy'] );

        parent::query($args);
    }

    function posts_join( $join, $query ) {
        if ( isset( $query->posts_by_taxonomy ) && false !== $query->posts_by_taxonomy ) {
            global $wpdb;
            $join .= $wpdb->prepare(
                 "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id={$wpdb->posts}.ID
                  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id={$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
                  AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy=%s",
                $this->taxonomy );
        }
        return $join;
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
$clients_query = new Query_By_Taxonomy(
    array(
      'post_type' => 'work',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'taxonomy' => 'clients',
  )
);
```